# MySQL insert where not with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.0

Objective:

- Using only MySQL, insert sku, tablename, slugs table when a sku & table name are not not already set.  I've got multiple tables that can have the same sku, but they are not the same.  So it needs to match on sku + tablename.

> ```
>  table1
>       SKU = 123
>       SKU = 234
> ```

```
table2
  SKU = 1234
  SKU = 123
  SKU = 45234

slugs final result should be like

slugs
  sku = 123 , table = table1
  sku = 234 , table = table1
  sku = 1234, table = table2
  sku = 123, table = table2
  sku = 45334, table = table2

I need to be able to look up sku's based off of the table name.
```

---

tables

```
CREATE TABLE `slugs` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `tablename` varchar(129) default NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `deleteme` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `NAME` varchar(160) default NULL COMMENT 'The products name.',
  `SKU` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'Advertisers unique identifier for the product.',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`SKU`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Broken MySQL code

```
INSERT INTO `slugs` (`sku`, `tablename`)
Select `SKU`, 'tableA'
from `tableA`
where not exists
(SELECT `slugs`.`sku` !=  `tableA`.`SKU` AND `slugs`.`tablename` !=  'tableA');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery, but if you have a unique constraint on the `sku` and `tablename` columns then you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` to get the same effect.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a "novice" at this can you give me an example of this?  I can change some aspects of the tables but not the id in the slugs table.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE \`slugs\` ADD UNIQUE INDEX(\`sku\`, \`tablename\`);`

Comment: I'm not sure that would work.  table1 might have sku = 123 and and table2 might have sku 123 also...

Comment: @Brad That index only enforces the uniqueness of the columns taken as a pair; it does not care whether there are duplicates within the individual columns.

Comment: With the Alter table I can just do:
INSERT IGNORE INTO `slugs` (`sku`, `tablename`) 
SELECT `SKU`, 'tableA' FROM `tableA`;
I'm testing the speed difference between this, and my answer...  which ever is fastest gets the green Check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using the following. Thanks to j_wright in an iRC

```
INSERT INTO `slugs` (`sku`, `tablename`)
SELECT `SKU`, 'tableA', `NAME` FROM `tableA`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT `sku`, `tablename` FROM `slugs`
     WHERE `sku` = `tableA`.`SKU` and `tablename` = 'tableA'
);
```

---OR THIS SEEMS TO WORK-------

```
INSERT INTO `slugs` (`sku`, `tablename`)
select `SKU`, 'tableA'
from `tableA`
WHERE `SKU` NOT IN
(select `sku` from `slugs` where `tablename` = 'tableA');
```